# Split linear data and calc max of data php

Tags: php, arrays, string, max

I have result calculation of my data like this :
0.0450.0230.0560.0620.0420.0100.0730.0470.0780.0570.0040.0550.0500.0500.039

I wanna calc MAX value for my data.
I have try this code:

```
//example
$data = 0.0450.0230.0560.0620.0420.0100.0730.0470.0780.0570.0040.0550.0500.0500.039;
$arr = str_split($data, 5); //it will be 5 characters like: 0.045 and 0.023
$max = max(array($arr)); //calc Max
```

The problem is my data value **absolutely/must** like :
0.0450.0230.0560.0620.0420.0100.0730.0470.0780.0570.0040.0550.0500.0500.039

I need your help, thank you :D

Comment: What kind of number is that? Why do you try to run `str_split`  on an input that is not a string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code has some errors, the logic is ok.

First, the `$data` variable should be a string:

`$data = "0.0450.0230.0560.0620.0420.0100.0730.0470.0780.0570.0040.0550.0500.0500.039";`

Second, take a look at this code:

`$max = max(array($arr));`

You are converting array into array. The $arr, is already an array. It should be like this:

`$max = max($arr);`

The `$max` variable now holds the maximum value.

Comment: I have try $max = max($arr); and show : 
max(): When only one parameter is given, it must be an array

Comment: @Gino `str_split` already returns an array. So there is no need to convert an array. I have tested the code with the above changes and it gave me the result: `0.078`. Please test it yourself.